# Timing of value assignment in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm a newbie to SQLAlchemy, so apologies if this is a really dumb question.

I have set up a simple 1-to-many parent/child relationship, without too much trouble, following the examples on the SQLA web site. However, I am have difficulties passing an initial value from the parent to the child when it is constructed.

My suspicion is that this has to do with the timing at which the members of the parent class are actually assigned values, but I'd really appreciate it if somebody could explain the 'correct' approach, or else some work-around.

My code is as follows

```
class FoobarDefinition(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('my_defn_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Foobar", backref="definition")

    start = Column(Integer, default=0)
    thing = Column(String, default="Widget")

    def createFoobar(self):
        foobar = Foobar(self.id, self.thing)
        self.children.append(foobar)
        return foobar

class Foobar(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('my_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    definition_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('FOOBAR_DEFINITION.id'))

    states = relationship("FoobarState", backref="Foobar")

    thing = Column(String)

    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    updated = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)

    def __init__(self, spec_id, thing):
        self.spec_id = spec_id
        self.thing = thing
```

The relevant part of the SQL log is as follows:

> 2014-05-18 17:27:07,678 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO "FOOBAR_DEFINITION" (start, thing) VALUES (?, ?)
>
> 2014-05-18 17:27:07,679 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (0, 'Widget')   <--- good
>
> 2014-05-18 17:27:07,680 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO "FOOBAR" (definition_id, thing, created, updated) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
>
> 2014-05-18 17:27:07,681 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1, None, '2014-05-18 17:27:07.680650', '2014-05-18 17:27:07.680668')   <--- bad (2nd arg is None)

The issue as shown here is that the insert into FOOBAR should have 'Widget' as its second value, rather than None. The value is propagated from the FOOBAR_DEFINITION, which is being inserted with a correct value of 'Widget'.

Any advice gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

This is only a problem in case your `FoobarDefinition` uses [`default`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default) value for `thing` column, because the value (`"Widget"`) on the instance is not set, but `only` inserted when the data is flushed to the database.

You can set a default value during new instance initialization, for example:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    self.thing = "Widget"
    # ...
```

or just always provide the value for this field.

Comment: Thank van. In the meantime, I think I've found a workaround (or maybe even the 'correct' solution). All I do is to make sure I commit my session after adding the FoobarDefinition, and before using it to create a Foobar. The causes the definition to be populated correctly, - including default values - which then get propagated to the Foobar, as intended. It makes the database interaction a bit chattier than I'd prefer, but is worth it if it makes the code function correctly.

Comment: If you `commit` (or just `flush`) the session after adding the FoobarDefinition, it will insert the data into database, and read (via `SELECT`) the object status back from DB into memory. This is why it works the way you do. I still feel this is not the best way, but as long as you are happy, so am I.

Comment: I'd prefer to do it the 'best' way, but I'm not convinced that setting it explicitly in Python code is it. I would prefer to use SQLA idioms where possible and to my mind, the 'default' option *ought* to be the way to set a default. It's just a shame that it doesn't work n the way that I want to use it :-(

Comment: I see. However, why would you think that setting default values in the `__init__` method is not conviencing? I would argue that if you did not use SA to persist your data, `__init__` would be exactly the place where you would assign default values to fields.

Comment: I see your point, but as I say, since I'm talking SQLA-ese, I'd rather use their idioms. Sadly, it doesn't work as I'd like it to. If the flush/commit approach hadn't worked, then I'd have reverted to the POP approach that you advise.